# if $x>0$ then $x≥0$? (Proof step)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

[image]

I am trying to prove the above theorem, but I couldn't figure out how to achieve the inequality "greater than or equal to."

I got to one of the last parts of the proof where $x+y > \sqrt {xy}$ and checked the solution. (This image is the solution)

**I don't understand how the solution simply states "Therefore: $x>0$ then $x≥0$".**

This doesn't make sense to me because $x$ is a positive real number and if $x>0$, $x$ could be any real number larger than $0$.

Comment: The symbol $\because$ is used by some to mean `because`, while $\therefore$ is the one used for `therefore`.

Comment: @fordjones The formatting is the same as in the answer field.

Comment: `\because` for $\because$ and `\therefore` for $\therefore$ The highlight is done by enclosing in this character (`).

Comment: I think you don’t fully grasp the meaning of the sentence “$x\ge y$”. It means that one of the two possibilities ($x>y$), ($x=y$) is true. Nothing more and nothing less. It does *not* mean that $x$ is sometimes greater, sometimes equal to, $y$.

Comment: mathguy, $x\ge 0$ means $x$ is greater OR equal to zero. So, if $x$ is greater zero, than it is obviously true that $x$ is greater OR equal to zero and thus $x\ge 0$. Note that A OR B is true if only one of both is true.

Comment: oh i see........

Comment: Strange that the problem asks for $\ge$ when $>$ is always true.

Comment: This is a rule of inference called "Disjunctive amplification/addition"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x \geq 0$ simply means $x$ is greater than or equal to zero. The logical connective or is true when at least one of its inputs is true, so if $x>0, x\geq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

$x\geq 0$ is equivalent to $x > 0 \lor x =0$

So, given that $x>0$, you can infer $x>0 \lor x=0$ (and thus $x \geq 0$) using $\lor$ Intro.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $$ a.b \implies a\ge b$$

Hence,
$$(x+y)> \sqrt {xy} \implies (x+y)- \sqrt {xy}>0$$

$$(x+y)- \sqrt {xy}>0 \implies  (x+y)- \sqrt {xy}\ge 0$$

$$(x+y)- \sqrt {xy}\ge 0 \implies (x+y)\ge \sqrt {xy}$$